# Subscript out of Range when attempting to close a Workbook

Tags: excel, vba

Can somebody help me? I have error in closing workbook in VBA

here's my code:

```
Sub CloseWb()

Dim Wb As Workbook
Dim path1 As String
Dim Source As String

Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SendEmail")
    
'Source = sh.Range("M2").Value
Workbooks(sh.Range("M2").Value).Close SaveChanges:=False  'cause of error

End Sub
```

Comment: That means `sh.Range("M2").Value` is not a name of an open workbook.

Comment: yes workbook included that cell this is the path file servername+ Template\2. Chapel\KRA Hr for Verification\Send Email\Chapel KRA HR Verification_DEC20.xlsx

Comment: Do you open the workbook with that same cell? If so, the explicit thing to do would be to set that book to a variable at time of opening and then just close the set variable. Otherwise, you just need to pass the book name + extension. Not the entire path